# I can't copy files to C:\Program Files through GPP

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy

I need to copy several files to `C:\Program Files` (WinXP) through GPP but it does not work. When I try to copy to `C:\` (root) it works fine. I have applied Win2k8 compatibility update with same results.

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try double quotes around the path since program files has a space

```
"C:\Program Files\path\"
```

Alternatively you can try %programfiles%

On a 64-bit machine running in 64-bit mode:

%programfiles% ==> C:\Program Files

%programfiles(x86)% ==> C:\Program Files (x86)

On a 64-bit machine running in 32-bit (WOW64) mode:

%programfiles% ==> C:\Program Files (x86)

%programfiles(x86)% ==> C:\Program Files (x86)